# Text and image between nav

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create two navigation bars with a Title and an image in between. This is what i currently have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
nav {
  float: right;
}

.site-info {
  float: right;
}
.site-avatar {
  float: right;
  height: 120px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
  <body>
  <header>
    <div class="topbar">
      <nav class="site-nav">LOREM IPSUM | LOREM IPSUM | LOREM IPSUM | LOREM IPSUM </nav>

      <a href="/"><img class="site-avatar" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg"></a>
      
      <div class="site-info">
        <h1><a href="/">Title</a></h1>
        <p class="site-description">Subtitle</p>
      </div>
      
      <nav class="content-nav">LOREM IPSUM | LOREM IPSUM | LOREM IPSUM | LOREM IPSUM </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to keep the text, navigation bars and the image floating to the right.

Image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Image of what I am trying to achieve]

Comment: can you show a picture of what you're trying to achieve? isn't very clear from your post.

Comment: something like this maybe? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNRrxj

Comment: @MichaelCoker Done.

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/NjRaZM

Comment: CSS clear seems to be what I need in this case. I will check and report back..

Comment: or just some sort of "clearfix"